# Python - Remove Special Characters from list

Tags: python, list, special-characters

I have a list of words and I want to remove all special characters and numbers, here is what I cam up with:

INPUT:
#convert all words to lowercase

```
words = [word.lower() for word in words]
print(words[:100])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['rt', '@', 'dark', 'money', 'has', 'played', 'a', 'significant', 'role', 'in', 'the', 'overall', 'increase', 'of', 'election', 'spending', 'in', 'state', 'judicial', 'elections.', 'https://e85zq', 'rt', '@', 'notice,', 'women,', 'how', 'you', 'are', 'always', 'the', 'target', 'of', 'democrats’', 'fear', 'mongering', 'in', 'an', 'election', 'year', 'or', 'scotus', 'confirmation.', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'because', 'our', 'rights', 'are', 'actually', 'at', 'risk.', 'it', 'is', 'because', 'we', 'are', 'easily', 'manipulated.', 'goes', 'allll', 'the', 'way', 'back', 'to', 'eve.', 'resist', 'hysteria', '&amp;', 'think.', 'rt', '@', 'oct', '5:', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'register', 'to', 'vote.', 'oct', '13:', 'early', 'voting', 'starts.', 'oct', '23:', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'request', 'a', 'mail-in', 'ballot.', 'nov', '3:', 'election', 'day', 'rt', '@']
```

INPUT

```
words_cleaned = [re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", i) for i in words]

print(words_cleaned[:100])
```

OUTPUT

I end up with an empty string []

What I need is characters like '@' to be removed, and a character like '@test' to turn to 'test'.  any ideas?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: may I suggest *you* read up on regular expressions?  `.` doesn't mean any character when it is inside a character class `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Hello @andrew-seaman, your code is perfectly working on my notebook. Can you try your code again or upload your entire code here?

Comment: @LukeWoodward well isn't that some egg on my face! OP, your code works fine. Please include a complete [mre] that reproduces your problem

Comment: ''.join(e for e in string if e.isalpha())

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all non-letters chars, try:

```
words = ["".join(filter(lambda c: c.isalpha(), word)) for word in words]
print(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in shortcuts rather than have to specify all of the special characters.  Here's a way to remove everything but "word characters":

import re

```
inp = ['rt', '@', 'dark', 'money', 'has', 'played', 'a', '#significant', 'role', 'in', 'tRhe', 'overall', 'increase', 'of', 'election', 'spending', 'in', 'state', 'judicial', 'elections.', 'https://e85zq', 'rt', '@', 'notice,', 'women,', 'how', 'you', 'are', 'always', 'the', 'target', 'of', 'democrats’', 'fear', 'mongering', 'in', 'an', 'election', 'year', 'or', 'scotus', 'confirmation.', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'because', 'our', 'rights', 'are', 'actually', 'at', 'risk.', 'it', 'is', 'because', 'we', 'are', 'easily', 'manipulated.', 'goes', 'allll', 'the', 'way', 'back', 'to', 'eve.', 'resist', 'hysteria', '&amp;', 'think.', 'rt', '@', 'oct', '5:', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'register', 'to', 'vote.', 'oct', '13:', 'early', 'voting', 'starts.', 'oct', '23:', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'request', 'a', 'mail-in', 'ballot.', 'nov', '3:', 'election', 'day', 'rt', '@']

outp = [re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+", '', s) for s in inp]

print(outp)
```

Result:

```
['rt', '', 'dark', 'money', 'has', 'played', 'a', 'significant', 'role', 'in', 'tRhe', 'overall', 'increase', 'of', 'election', 'spending', 'in', 'state', 'judicial', 'elections', 'httpse85zq', 'rt', '', 'notice', 'women', 'how', 'you', 'are', 'always', 'the', 'target', 'of', 'democrats', 'fear', 'mongering', 'in', 'an', 'election', 'year', 'or', 'scotus', 'confirmation', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'because', 'our', 'rights', 'are', 'actually', 'at', 'risk', 'it', 'is', 'because', 'we', 'are', 'easily', 'manipulated', 'goes', 'allll', 'the', 'way', 'back', 'to', 'eve', 'resist', 'hysteria', 'amp', 'think', 'rt', '', 'oct', '5', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'register', 'to', 'vote', 'oct', '13', 'early', 'voting', 'starts', 'oct', '23', 'last', 'day', 'to', 'request', 'a', 'mailin', 'ballot', 'nov', '3', 'election', 'day', 'rt', '']
```

The `^` character here means match everything NOT mentioned in the set of characters that follow inside a `[]` pair.  `\w` means "word characters"
.  So the whole thing says "match everything but word characters."  The nice thing about using a regular expression is that you can get arbitrarily precise as to just which characters you want to include or exclude.

No need to slice the result with `[:100` to print it.  Just print it as is, like I do.  I assume that by using `100`, you're wanting to make sure you go to the end of the list.  The better way to do that is to just leave that component blank.  So `[:]` means "take a slice of the string that is the full string", and `[5:]` means "take from the 6th character to the end of the string".

UPDATE: I just noticed that you said you don't want numbers in the result. So then I guess you just want letters.  I changed the expression to do that.  This is what's nice about a regular expression.  You can tweak just what gets replaced without adding additional calls, loops, etc. but rather just change a string value.

Comment: Not the case. As Luke noted in comments, `.` inside a character class `[...]` doesn't need to be escaped. OP's code works just fine.

Comment: Something changed.  I don't have a copy of it, but when I ran his code the first time, I swear I got an empty output, which is what he said he got too.

Comment: Could _that_ be why I also thought `.` needed to be escaped in the first place? Sneaky OP!